# Swift - Waiting time for alamofire to finish

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am simply trying to get latitude and longitude of a city. But before alamofire can complete the request I receive the defined value of 0.0 which is not what I want. I do get the values of latitude and longitude but 0.0 has already been passed so the app takes that only.

I have tried completion block but it didn't work. I tried little tricks here and there but nothing worked. How should I improve this?

```
func getAddress(address:String){

    let key : String = "<API_KEY>"
    let postParameters:[String: Any] = [ "address": address,"key":key]
    let url : String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
    var lat = 0.0
    var long = 0.0

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: postParameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        response in if let receivedResults = response.result.value
        {
            let resultParams = JSON(receivedResults)
            print(resultParams["status"]) // OK, ERROR
            lat = resultParams["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"].doubleValue// approximately latitude
            long = resultParams["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"].doubleValue // approximately longitude
            print("Here i am \(self.destLatitude)")
        }
        self.destLatitude = lat
        self.destLongitude = long
        print("Here i am also \(self.destLatitude)")
    }
}
```

Expected output is latitude and longitude of a place.

Comment: If you have tried a completion block then you probably did it incorrectly since this is a typical question about asynchronous callbacks that has been asked so many times before.

Comment: Almofire always runs the request on background thread by default and returns the data in asynchronous way. Try googling about what both of the term means if you want more in depth knowledge. 

In your case assign the new values to your globals inside the closure so that it will only update the values when it gets the response from server.

Answer (score 2):

The network request works asynchronously, assign the values to the properties inside the completion handler

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: postParameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
    response in if let receivedResults = response.result.value
    {
        let resultParams = JSON(receivedResults)
        print(resultParams["status"]) // OK, ERROR
        lat = resultParams["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"].doubleValue// approximately latitude
        long = resultParams["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"].doubleValue // approximately longitude
        self.destLatitude = lat
        self.destLongitude = long
        print("Here i am \(self.destLatitude)")
    }
}
```